# Custom css by php methods

Tags: php, html, css, customization

I'm doing my business practises in a company and i already recieve a project that consist in make the client possible to custom the header and background color.

They told me I have to develop a method to implement it!

So I thought to add a comment line into the style.css to detect the line and change just the next.

**I did something like that:**
[image]

```
//linia para encontrar lo que queremos
                        $linea_css = "upload_header_bgcolor";
                        // intentamos abrir el fichero .dat del usuario y recoger su contenido (es posible que no exista)
                        $contenidoFichero = @file_get_contents(self::$dir_inetpub . "/" . $this->parametros["site"] . "/software/css/style.css");
                        $arrFichero = array();

                        if ($contenidoFichero !== false)
                            $arrFichero = explode("\r\n", $contenidoFichero);
                            // buscamos la linea a eliminar y la borramos de la array en caso de encontrarla
                            $encontrado = false;
                            for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrFichero) && !$encontrado; $i++)
                            {
                                if ($arrFichero[$i] == $linea_css)
                                {
                                    $arrFichero[$i+1] = "background: ". $this->parametros['color'] . " !important;";
                                    $encontrado = true;
                                }
                            }
```

It makes right the file backup with the .bak extension, the problem is:
- The method doesn't overwrite well the style.css, cause it has no changes

Comment: Why not use a single file to perform the change using `style.php` php extension ?

Comment: its what i told them, but they still want like this way... :/ anyway i could fix it! thanks anyway mate :D